# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains "insert app directory path here"

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-flavors

I am opening the camera to capture a image and i followed [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). Error stated in the title comes when i tried to create different flavor builds configuration for my app.

This is my meta data xml resource file named **file_paths** for File Provider path configuration -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="@string/images_file_path"/>
</paths>
```

I am setting it in manifest as follows -

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and i am instantiating string resource named "images_file_path" from gradle build file according to build congiguration like this -

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        resValue "string", "images_file_path","\"Android/data/com.swinguff.android.dev/files/Pictures\""
    }
    prod {
        resValue "string", "images_file_path","\"Android/data/com.swinguff.android/files/Pictures\""
    }
```

and i am launching camera in my activity like this -

```
File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            if (photoFile != null) {
            /*Following line is throwing the error */
            profilePicUri =
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(ApplicationContext.getAppContext(),
                        BuildConfig.AUTHORITY,
                        photoFile);
                launchcamera();
                //Log.d("Musik","camera bug take photo"+photoFile+" "+mPhotoPathForCamera+" "+profilePicUri);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.d("CAMERA_BUG","exception "+ex.getMessage()+"\n"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"\n"+BuildConfig.AUTHORITY
                +"\n"+getString(R.string.images_file_path));
            Util.showSnackbar(xRoot,getString(R.string.camera__open_error));

        }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    npath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Same code does not cause any exception when i set value of **path** property in above meta data xml resource as a literal string and not by a resouce string value.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Please let me know if i can explain better.Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply put file_paths.xml file into your flavors paths. Like dev/main/src/res/xml/file_paths.xml and prod/main/src/res/xml/file_paths.xml. And just write full path without using string resource and resValue config.

Comment: @Miller Thank you so much , your solution works .....but i still don't get why it is not setting properly by resource string

Comment: Using string resource, you can just override this string resource in your strings.xml for different flavours. No need for productFlavors section in gradle config. I guess it's a root of problem, compiler can't use gradle config to decode string value.

Comment: @Miller ahh..okay i got it....Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

as [Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128938/miller) pointed out in the comments the solution is to put meta data xml resource file **file_paths.xml** separately for each build in their corresponding (dev/res/xml or prod/res/xml) folder and set corresponding path value directly in xml file and not by string resource **images_file_path**

Answer (score 0):

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

see this edit your paths like this your problem will solve